# Handling Multiple config file in c#

Tags: c#, config

So basically I have a simple Application which reads a database, and I have a configuration file with the path of the database. I have multiple databases and therefore I want to have multiple configuration files which i can use with this application. Is it possible to have a variable be defining which configuration to use. I would like to define the configuration to use as a command line parameter.

eg. `myapp.exe app1.config`

OR

eg. `myapp.exe app2.config`

After defining the paramenter, the application should chose the configuration file accordingly

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultipleConfig
{
    /* Note :- Create multiple config files.
    */

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configFile.ExeConfigFilename = "MyConfig.config";

            Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;

            string fName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirstName"];
            string lName = settings["LastName"].Value;
            string country = settings["Country"].Value;

            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat(fName, " ", lName, "\nCountry ", country), this.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration` method which will allow you to read a configuration file passed in command line parameters. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find a more detailed description together with an example.

So it is possible, however according to me the more convenient option is to have multiple configuration sections in the one (default) configuration file and choose the correct one based on command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have used my own config file mechanism before .NET and nothing stops you from writing your own code.

You can only have one active app.config but hey, you can have as many files as you want and program your own reading routines. All it takes is some pages of code to load them and make them available via static variables.